# How to Run C# tasks in Sequence

Tags: c#, multithreading

For examples, I have 10 tasks. I want to run x tasks in the same time, if any task finish, other tasks will be added to run.
It likes queues in Internet Download Manager

Comment: Is it an important order of executing tasks? Can you wait until all executed? Are you returning something from task?

Comment: Any research to show?  [ask]

Comment: Use TPL Dataflow. Does exactly what you need.

Comment: @kat1330 Ignore order. It likes queues in Internet Download Manager

Comment: @killerX Then you can use `Task.WhenAll()`. I added below.

Answer (score 1):

As Cory Nelson pointed out, the [Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow) does what you need. Start by adding the nuget package, then instantiate an `ActionBlock` with the settings you want:

```
var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<string>(new Action<string>(Execute), new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 });
```

Here, it will call the `Execute` method for every string you enqueue (the payload could be something else, here I'm assuming the string is the url of the file you wish to download). That `ActionBlock` will ensure that no more than 10 threads are running concurrently.

Use the `Post` method to enqueue some work:

```
actionBlock.Post("http://.../");
```

Here is a simple proof of concept:

```
class Program
{
    private static int ConcurrentActions = 0;

    public static void Main()
    {
        var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<string>(new Action<string>(Execute), new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 });

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            actionBlock.Post(i.ToString());
        }

        actionBlock.Complete();

        while (!actionBlock.Completion.IsCompleted)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Concurrent actions: {0}", ConcurrentActions);

            Thread.Sleep(200);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void Execute(string url)
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref ConcurrentActions);

        Thread.Sleep(1000); // Workload

        Interlocked.Decrement(ref ConcurrentActions);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to chain the tasks ? As in once 1st task finishes the 2nd one starts ?

You can use ContinueWith()

Refer msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537612(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Use: Parallel.Invoke - MSDN Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Just [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42799714/edit) your answer, don't post revisions as a comment

Comment: It's slightly more complex than that. OP wants that at any point in time, there is x tasks running concurrently. Using `ContinueWith`,you'd have to predict the order the tasks will finish

Answer (score 0):

> For examples, I have 10 tasks. I want to run x tasks in the same time

This is a concurrency throttling scenario.

If by "task", you mean some CPU-bound code that you want to run (that is, each "task" is *synchronous* in nature), then the appropriate tool would be to set `DegreeOfParallelism` on a `Parallel` or PLINQ call, something like:

```
data.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(x).Select(d => ...).ToList();
```

If by "task", you mean an actual `Task` (that is, each "task" is *asynchronous* in nature), then the appropriate tool would be to use a `SemaphoreSlim` with `Task.WhenAll`, something like:

```
var throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(x);
var tasks = data.Select(async d =>
{
  await throttler.WaitAsync();
  try { ... }
  finally { throttler.Release(); }
}).ToList();
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Alternatively, you could [use TPL Dataflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42803495/263693), which will work with either synchronous or asynchronous "task"s.